# Can't connect RabbitMQ node to cluster

Tags: rabbitmq

I've just installed rabbitmq on 2 new VMs and tried to create a simple two node cluster. I've copied the erlang cookie file from one machine to both locations on that machine (C:\Users{username} and C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile) and  those locations on the other machine as well.

When I try to join one to the other to create a cluster using the rabbitmqctl join_cluster command, I get the following output:

```
Clustering node rabbit@{machinename1} with rabbit@{machinename2}
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@{machinename2}. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on http://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@{machinename2}

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['{machinename2}']

rabbit@{machinename2}:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on {machinename2}
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed

  * Hostname mismatch: node "rabbit@{machinename2}" believes its host is different. Please ensure that hostnames resolve the same way locally and on "rabbit@{machinename2}"


Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli60@{machinename1}'
 * effective user's home directory: {homedirectory}
 * Erlang cookie hash: {hash}
```

Everyone on the internet seems to be saying that this is caused by having cookie mismatches, but I've verified that they're the same. What am I missing here?

Running Erlang OTP 20.2 and rabbitMQ 3.7.3

Comment: Did you configure the `hosts` file in `machinename1` for `machinename2`?

Comment: `Hostname mismatch: node "rabbit@{machinename2}" believes its host is different.` - what does the `hostname` command output on this machine? Compare that with the output of the `join_cluster` command.

Comment: When I run the hostname command, I get the same machine name. As for bumblebee's question, no I haven't modified the hosts file. However, I'm not sure why that would be necessary. I can ping the other machine, and rabbitmq says it was able to connect but that the Erlang distribution failed.

Comment: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/1190

Comment: To come back to this, I recreated both VMs from scratch, installed Erlang and RabbitMQ, did everything the same as far as I can tell, and this time it worked. I have no idea what the problem was before.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that `join_cluster` is case sensitive when it comes to the machine name.

Comment: I think you should use a comment.